# (C++) Why is my program not outputting average wait time and average time over 1 hour?

Tags: c++, queue

This is a program that simulates a line for a teacher's office hours using queues. It generates a random number of students gives them each a random amount of time spent in the office, and adds them to the queue. It is also supposed to calculate the average time each student spent waiting, and whether the office hours go over 1 hour.

It is also supposed to run this 100 times and take the averages of all of them.

However, whenever I run it, the wait time and the time over 1 hour all show up as 0 and I can't really figure out why. I'm sure it's just some minor thing I'm overlooking but for whatever reason I can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything about my code or question.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //used for the time(x) function & difftime.
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Student{
public:
  int timeInOffice, arrivalTime, waitTime;
};

int main(){
  int numOfStudents;
  queue<Student> officeLine;
  int avgWaitFinal = 0, avgTimeInOfficeFinal = 0, avgTimeOverFinal = 0;
  //avgWaitFinal is the final average wait time
  //avgTimeinOfficeFinal is the final average time spent in office
  //avgTimeOverFinal is the average time over 1 hour spent in the office.
  for (int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
    numOfStudents = rand()%10+1;
    //This picks a random number of student between 1 and 10
    for (int j=0; j < numOfStudents; j++){
      Student st;
      st.timeInOffice = rand()%10+1;
      //this picks a random time spent in the office between 1 and 10 minutes.
      st.arrivalTime = time(0);
      officeLine.emplace(st);
    }
    int avgWait = 0, avgTimeInOffice = 0;
    time_t officeArrivalTime = time(0);
    while (! officeLine.empty()){
      Student s = officeLine.front();
      s.waitTime = time(0);
      avgWait += (int)std::round(difftime(s.waitTime, s.arrivalTime));
      avgTimeInOffice += s.timeInOffice;
      officeLine.pop();
    }
    time_t outTime = time(0);
    int totalTime = (int)std::round(difftime(outTime, officeArrivalTime));
    //this takes the difference between the time the student left and the time they arrived to calculate the total time they spent in the office.
    int timeOver = totalTime > 60 ? (totalTime - 60) : 0;
    avgTimeOverFinal += timeOver;
    avgWait = avgWait/numOfStudents;
    avgWaitFinal += avgWait;
    avgTimeInOffice = avgTimeInOffice/numOfStudents;
    avgTimeInOfficeFinal += avgTimeInOffice;
    cout<<"Run #: "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of Students: "<< numOfStudents<<endl;
    cout<<"Average Wait Time: "<<avgWait<<endl;
    cout<<"Average Visit Time: "<<avgTimeInOffice<<endl;
    cout<<"Time Over 1 Hour: "<<timeOver<<endl;
    //These are the stats for each individual run of the program
    cout<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Overall Average Wait Time: "<< (avgWaitFinal/100)<<endl;
  cout<<"Overall Average Time in Office: "<< (avgTimeInOfficeFinal/100)<<endl;
  cout<<"Overall Average Time Over 1 Hour: "<< (avgTimeOverFinal/100)<<endl;
  //these are the final averages of 100 runs
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is the kind of situation that a debugger is meant for. Run your code inside a debugger, so you can step through the code line by line, watching what each statement does, and when its behavior is not what you are expecting then you can stop the program and fix it. Debugging is an essential skill for any developer to learn, so now is a good time to do that.

Comment: Integers are not very useful for averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `difftime` many times between time variables set to `time(0)`: they end up assuming the same value because they get initialised almost at the same time.
Hence I have added `rand()` terms to them; pick these values more accurately if you wish.

Also, inside the `while`-loop, I have changed the `s` student items to be pointers to the `queue` structure, so no new instances of these objects are created.

There is a useful suggestion in the comments under your question: leave `double` values when taking averages, and round them off as `int` only afterwards.

Here is my revised version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //used for the time(x) function & difftime.
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Student{
public:
  int timeInOffice, arrivalTime, waitTime;
};

int main(){
  int numOfStudents;
  queue<Student> officeLine;
  int avgWaitFinal = 0, avgTimeInOfficeFinal = 0, avgTimeOverFinal = 0;
  //avgWaitFinal is the final average wait time
  //avgTimeinOfficeFinal is the final average time spent in office
  //avgTimeOverFinal is the average time over 1 hour spent in the office.
  for (int i=1; i <= 100; i++){
    numOfStudents = rand()%10+1;
    //This picks a random number of student between 1 and 10
    for (int j=0; j < numOfStudents; j++){
      Student st;
      st.timeInOffice = rand()%10+1;
      //this picks a random time spent in the office between 1 and 10 minutes.
      st.arrivalTime = time(0) + rand()%10+1;
      officeLine.emplace(st);
    }
    double avgWait = 0, avgTimeInOffice = 0;
    time_t officeArrivalTime = time(0);
    while ( !officeLine.empty() ){
      Student* s = &officeLine.front();
      s->waitTime = time(0);
      avgWait += difftime(s->arrivalTime, s->waitTime);
      avgTimeInOffice += s->timeInOffice;
      officeLine.pop();
    }
    time_t outTime = time(0) + rand()% 100 + 1;
    double totalTime = difftime(outTime, officeArrivalTime);
    //this takes the difference between the time the student left and the time they arrived to calculate the total time they spent in the office.
    int timeOver = totalTime > 60 ? (totalTime - 60) : 0;
    avgTimeOverFinal += timeOver;
    avgWait = std::round(avgWait/numOfStudents);
    avgWaitFinal += avgWait;
    avgTimeInOffice = std::round(avgTimeInOffice/numOfStudents);
    avgTimeInOfficeFinal += avgTimeInOffice;
    cout<<"Run #: "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of Students: "<< numOfStudents<<endl;
    cout<<"Average Wait Time: "<<avgWait<<endl;
    cout<<"Average Visit Time: "<<avgTimeInOffice<<endl;
    cout<<"Time Over 1 Hour: "<<timeOver<<endl;
    //These are the stats for each individual run of the program
    cout<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Overall Average Wait Time: "<< (avgWaitFinal/100)<<endl;
  cout<<"Overall Average Time in Office: "<< (avgTimeInOfficeFinal/100)<<endl;
  cout<<"Overall Average Time Over 1 Hour: "<< (avgTimeOverFinal/100)<<endl;
  //these are the final averages of 100 runs
return 0;
}
```